# UIView removeFromSuperview calls viewWillDisappear

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview

I have a custom `navigation` implemented but I have a problem.

After I pop a `UIViewController`, I manually call `viewWillDisappear`, but for some reason it gets called again when I call `removeFromSuperview` for that `UIViewController's` `UIView`.

How can I stop that from happening? This happens for `iOS 6`, I am sure it doesn't for `iOS 4`, I haven't tested for iOS 5. I am already using:

```
 - (BOOL)automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers {
     return NO;
}
```

but it doesn't help.

I am not using `dismissViewControllerAnimated`. I have implemented a custom Navigation Controller, I use my own stack, and "Push" and "Pop" the UIViewControllers by animating their view on and offscreen, and I call `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` manually. The problem is that after I "Pop" a `UIViewController` off screen, when I call `[currentViewController.view removeFromSuperView]` the `viewWillDisappear` method gets called, and I don't want that, as I already called it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the new view controller containment APIs? (`addChildViewController` etc.)? If so, they will automatically call `viewWillDisappear:` for you.

Comment: No, I am not. But I found the solution, I answered just below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. The problem was that I was calling `[controller.view removeFromSuperview]` and I noticed in the call stack that `[UIViewcontroller _setViewState:animated]` was called. So I did a small hack:

```
UIView *view = controller.view;
controller.view = nil;
[view removeFromSuperView];
[controller release];
```

Now, viewWillDisappear isn't called anymore when call [view removeFromSuperview]. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

try and use this ....

Comment: I am not using dismissViewControllerAnimated. I have implemented a custom Navigation Controller, I use my own stack, and "Push" and "Pop"  the UIViewControllers by animating their view on and offscreen, and I call viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear manually. The problem is that after I "Pop" a UIViewController off screen, when I call [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperView] the viewWillDisappear method gets called, and I don't want that, as I already called it.

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; > always 'wrong' IMO... the modal view controller shouldnt know it is presented. the presenter should call dismiss